Copy multiple row and paste in other sheet skipping 5 row
Could someone help me out with a vba code.
I have to copy a range of cells from Sheet 1 and paste them in Sheet 2 skipping 5th row.
In particular the copy range is A1:M45 (45 row). The range is fixed
The paste area (Sheet 2) start in A5:M5 skipping 5 row like this


A5:M5

A10:M10

A15:M15

A20:M20

A225:M225


I tried with this code but I can't select a range but only a column and I can't define a start/end cell.
Sub Test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lngRowCounter As Long
    Dim lngRowMultiplier As Long

    lngRowCounter = 1
    lngRowMultiplier = 5

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Do While Not IsEmpty(ws1.Range("A" & lngRowCounter))
        ws2.Range("A" & lngRowCounter * lngRowMultiplier).Value = _
            ws1.Range("A" & lngRowCounter).Value
        lngRowCounter = lngRowCounter + 1
    Loop
End Sub


There are many ways to achieve this. Here is one. Is this what you are trying?
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Long: rw = 5
    Dim i As Long
    
    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheets
    Set wsA = Sheet1
    Set wsB = Sheet2
    
    For i = 1 To 45
        wsA.Rows(i).Copy wsB.Rows(rw)
        rw = rw + 5
    Next i
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub


I noticed that it copies the entire row, not just from A to M. I would like to define the columns to copy (A-M) and the cell from which to paste the values. (E.g.. V7)

Replace wsA.Rows(i).Copy wsB.Rows(rw) with wsA.Range("A" & i & ":M" & i).Copy wsB.Range("A" & rw & ":M" & rw)

It works fine. Is it possibile a PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ?

Replace wsA.Rows(i).Copy wsB.Rows(rw) in the above code with wsB.Range("A" & rw & ":M" & rw).Value = wsA.Range("A" & i & ":M" & i).Value

It seems like I can't choose the columns where to paste but only the columns where to copy.

My code is based on the question that you asked. Your question says fixed input and output columns... You have to be more specific as to what your requirement is... BTW wsB.Range("A" & rw & ":M" & rw) is where you specify the output columns.

This is for how formulas can be used.
=WRAPROWS(TOROW(HSTACK(Sheet1!A1:M80,Sheet1!N1:BR80),FALSE,FALSE),14)

Sheet1!N1:BR80 is only for filling the 4 mid-rows. Can be any range which is empty.
I don't know what is the limit of these functions. With 80 rows it is tested.
